# Difference between ASP.NET caches

Tags: c#, .net, caching

What's the difference between:

1. `HttpRuntime.Cache["key"]`
2. `HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"]`
3. `HttpContext.Current.Application["key"]`

are there any major differences between these memories?

Comment: FYI, those are ASP.NET caches, not IIS caches.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.Cache` and `HttpRuntime.Cache` are the same, the context cache prop just returns the runtime Cache. `HttpRuntime` and `HttpContext` just return handles to this object.

`HttpRuntime.Cache` is recommended but likely won't make a difference in most applications.

`HttpContext.Current.Application` is not a cache, its a global named value collection. if you add an object to Application it will stay until a an appdomain recycle. If you put an object in cache, it not guaranteed to be there when you fetch it. The cache is free to throw it away if the cache get too large, or the object has fetched often enough.